# Am I missing any pre-processing step to data when doing outlier detection using Isolation-Forest for time series human sensor data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, outliers, isolation-forest

I am working on human sensor data and want to remove outliers if any from the dataset. The data is collected 50times per second. My question is do I need to some pre-processing before using the Isolation-Forest model as I don't any error as such but want to use it in the right way. I have never worked with time series data before so any suggestions would be great.

The first 20 rows of the data is shown below:
[image: Human activity sensor data]

after reading the file I am extracting the sensor columns and using it on the model straight away.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

data = pd.read_csv('walking.csv')

# Specify the columns that contain sensor readings (exclude 'act' and 'id' columns)
sensor_columns = ['rotationRate.x', 'rotationRate.y', 'rotationRate.z',
                   'userAcceleration.x', 'userAcceleration.y', 'userAcceleration.z'] 

# Combine all sensor columns into a feature vector
X = data[sensor_columns]

# Define a range of contamination values to test
contamination_values = np.arange(0.01, 0.11, 0.01)  # Adjust the range as needed

# Create an empty list to store cross-validation scores
cv_scores = []

# Initialize time-based cross-validation
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5)  # You can adjust the number of splits as needed

# Loop through each contamination value and evaluate the model with time-based cross-validation
for contamination in contamination_values:
    scores = []
    for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(X):
        X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
        
        clf = IsolationForest(contamination=contamination, random_state=42)
        clf.fit(X_train)
        outlier_predictions = clf.predict(X_test)
        
        scores.append(np.mean(outlier_predictions == -1))  # Calculate the proportion of outliers
        
    cv_scores.append(np.mean(scores))

# Find the best contamination value with the highest cross-validation score
best_contamination = contamination_values[np.argmax(cv_scores)]
print("Best Contamination Value:", best_contamination)

# Train the final model with the best contamination value on the entire dataset
clf = IsolationForest(contamination=best_contamination, random_state=42)
clf.fit(X)
outlier_predictions = clf.predict(X)

# Create a new column to mark outliers in your original DataFrame
data['is_outlier'] = outlier_predictions

# Print the number of outliers detected
print("Number of Outliers Detected:", np.sum(outlier_predictions == -1))
```

I get the no. of outliers along with a warning which says X does not have valid feature names, but Isolation-Forest was fitted with feature names